# Как записать строки файла в массив, при достижении определенного слова?

Tags: python

я пишу бота Telegram.    Его задача это выдавать определенные тексты, которые записаны в текстовой файл.
Текстов много, поэтому я старался создать систему, которая по достижении ключевого слова, отделяет между собой эти тексты и каждый из них записывает в отдельный элемент массива.

Например:

% конец %

текст
текст

%конец%

текст

где %конец% разделяет между собой два разных текста, а текст это то что надо записать в ячейку массива.

Для начала я написал код который ищет в тексте номера строк со словом % конец%, но вот дальше я вошел в ступор.
Как мне выделить строки, которые лежат между двумя строками %конец%, и записать их в элемент массива?
Я начал изучать питон недавно, пытался все сделать сам, но тут все же не понимаю что делать. Заранее благодарю вас за помощь.

Вот все что мне удалось написать:

```
import re
d=[] #массив со строками, содержащие %end%
f=[] #массив содержащий все строки, а в конце - все строки, но без строк %end%
amount = len(re.findall(r"[\n']+?", open('apis.txt', encoding=("utf-8")).read())) 
with open('apis.txt', 'rt', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        for inde, line in enumerate(file, 1):
            f.append(inde)
print(f)
with open('apis.txt', 'rt', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for index, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if "%end%" in line:
            d.append(index)
            f.remove(index)
print(d)
print(f)
```

Comment: покажите ваш код, чтобы люди могли помочь вам, модифицируя ваш код, а не создавая код с нуля

Comment: совсем забыл, уже добавил!

Comment: как вы получаете ваше `f` ?

Comment: Я получаю значения массива f из текстового файла apis.txt. Считывается каждый номер строки и записывается в элементы массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt = '''
где %конец% разделяет между собой два разных текста, а текст это то что надо записать в ячейку массива. %конец%
Для начала я написал код который ищет в тексте номера строк со словом %конец%, но вот дальше я вошел в ступор.
 Как мне выделить строки, которые лежат между двумя строками %конец%, и записать их в элемент массива?
'''
f = txt.split('%конец%')
print(f)

['\nгде ',
 ' разделяет между собой два разных текста, а текст это то что надо записать в ячейку массива.', '\nДля начала я написал код который ищет в тексте номера строк со словом ',
 ', но вот дальше я вошел в ступор.\n Как мне выделить строки, которые лежат между двумя строками ',
 ', и записать их в элемент массива?\n']
```

Comment: Благодарю! Вы меня натолкнули на правильную мысль! Только вместе с split я использовал атрибут maxsplit, значение которого ровно количеству моих текстов и все получилось!  Все ровно разделилось.